# How can I handle an error locally and skip an Angular HTTP interceptor?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular `HttpInterceptor` to catch errors and display appropriate, yet generic, error messages depending on the status code.

I have a specific case where I actually *expect* and error message (the UI tries to release a lock on a resource that has just been deleted, so I get 404).

In that case I want to handle the error directly where I make the API call, and skip the interceptor.

I tried this:

```
releaseReviewerLock(itemType: EquipmentItemType, itemId: EquipmentItem["id"]): Observable<void> {
  return this.http
    .post<void>(`${this.configUrl}/${itemType.toLowerCase()}/${itemId}/release-reviewer-lock/`, {})
    .pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        if (e.status === HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
          // We can ignore the 404 because the item has just been deleted, so there's nothing to release.
          return EMPTY;
        }
      })
    );
}
```

But not only is my intercepto called anyway, the `catchError` block above is not executed at all (breakpoint didn't stop).

Can I achieve what I want without modifying the interceptor and keeping a resemblance of single-responsibility?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `HttpInterceptor` will always catch the error first, before it gets the `catchError` in the service. You may have to rethrow the error (`return throwError(error); `) from the interceptor for this specific case, then it will reach your service `catchError`.

Comment: If the interceptor catches it first, then it will display a generic error notification that I don't want in this case. And this means that I have to add specific error handling to the interceptor, e.g. `if (path.indexOf("release-reviewe-lock") > -1 && err.status === 404) {...}` which is ugly :(

Comment: Not sure there is another way, i'd also be interested to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can pass [some metadata context](https://angular.io/guide/http#passing-metadata-to-interceptors) to `HttpClient` and then retrieve it inside the `HttpInterceptor`.

Of course, it implies to add some logic inside `HttpInterceptor`, but thanks to metadata context, this code could be more versatile, and stay simple.

For example:

In `api.service.ts` :

```js
this.httpClient
  .get('http://...', {
    context: new HttpContext().set(IGNORED_STATUSES, [404]),
  })
  .pipe(
    catchError((e) => {
      console.log('Error catched locally', e);
      return of(EMPTY);
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

In `error.interceptor.ts` :

```js
export const IGNORED_STATUSES = new HttpContextToken<number[]>(() => []);

export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const ignoredStatuses = req.context.get(IGNORED_STATUSES);

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((e: HttpErrorResponse) => {

        // if ignored statuses are set
        // and returned status matched 
        if (ignoredStatuses?.includes(e.status)) {
          // rethrow error to be catched locally
          return throwError(() => e);
        }

        // process error...
        console.log('error interceptor !!', e);
        return of();
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this!

Comment: I liked this too, but as a best practice, should we handle all errors at interceptors? I guess we should huh ?